# Python Tensorflow Lite Interpreter Crashes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I see that tensorflow.contrib.lite.Interpreter was recently exposed in the python API.  However, when I build and install the tensorflow wheel from source per the [standard Tensorflow installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/install/install_sources) in Ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.5 using the repo head as of 5/22 (4dbaa65), I get a segmentation fault when I try to run it:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: a = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter('mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite')
In [3]: a.get_input_details()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: Can you file a github issue? This is a bug.

Comment: Github issue filed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19505

Comment: There was a bug, which has been fixed in the github issue above.